# Nicescroll scrolling with steps

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, mousewheel, parallax, smooth-scrolling

We are building parallax website with horizontal scrolling. We've used nicescroll plugin to have smooth hardware accelerated (where available) scrolling.

But we can't find out how to define scroll step in nicescroll.

This is what we want to have with nicescroll: [animated steps](http://sis.runningtime.am/scroll-step.html). Here we have used [jquery mousewheel](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) plugin to find direction of scroll and animate by defined step.

This is the same page with [nicescroll plugin](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/): [default nicescroll](http://sis.runningtime.am/scroll-nicescroll.html).

And this is nicescroll version mixed with first version: [nicescroll steps](http://sis.runningtime.am/scroll-step2.html)

The problem is that I doubt that we use nicescroll right in last version, as the scrolling is not so smooth. We want to have very smooth scrolling because we will also have some small parallax animation which can be seen only if scrolling is smooth and without any freezes.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.